# Using non-standard serial baud rate

Tags: serial-port

I am using a module that REQUIRES 28800 baud for the serial link.
Is there any way to set this rate?
It should be possible since it is half 57600 which IS a standard baud rate.
Trying with Ubuntu 15.04.
I have tried stty and putty but both revert to the next lowest standard of 19200 baud.